# commenting on someone else's Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am beginning to use Jupyter Notebook.

I want students to comment on each other's Notebooks as part of a validation exercise.

I know how to insert markdown, etc., but have not found any 'automatic' way to identify a comment's author.  For example, comments that I insert in an MS Word document are prefaced with my initials.

Does anyone know if there is such a feature, or whether an author needs to manually enter their identify?

Thank you,

Colin

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jupyter/JK2aBod0tS8 for discussion of this question on the Project Jupyter discussion group.

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/ is a Jupyter notebook environment that supports commenting. (It's similar to Google Docs for notebooks.)